# How to remove gap between navigation and the header? Also between navigation and main content?

Tags: header, space, nav

How can I remove the gap between the navigation and the header? ALso between the nav and the main content?
Navigation buttons i.e. ul are in their perfect place. but black navigation bar is causing me lots of unnecessary troubles! I am unable to fix it!

here is my html

```
        <div id="header">
        <div id="header-container">
            Logo goes here!!
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="main-body">
        <h1>Contant here!</h1>
    </div>
```

here is my css code:

```
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}


body{

    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #cccccc;
}

#header{
    background: #FF9900;
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header-container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #000000;
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav .nav-container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 62px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.nav .nav-container ul{
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav .nav-container ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    background: #000000;
}

.nav .nav-container ul li a{
    color: #FF9900;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 58px;
    line-height: 250%;

}

.nav .nav-container ul li a:hover{
    background:#FF9900;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px; 
}

.main-body{
    width: 960px;
    background: white;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `margin-top: 5px;` to `margin-top: 0;` in `.nav .nav-container`.

```
.nav .nav-container{
    width: 960px;
    height: 62px;
    margin: auto;
    /* margin-top: 5px; becomes */ margin-top: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ue65t3gh/

Comment: Didn't work!! Also I added margin:auto to center the content!

Comment: @killerprince182 I added a demo. What "didn't work"?

Comment: there kis no space between menu items and the header.

Comment: Also there is space between content and the nav

Comment: @killerprince182 Great! Please accept an answer when you are able.